# How to use conditional formatting to progressively turn green to red as the distance between two dates increases

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[My Excel sheet that I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrbFz.png)

Cell B3 contains a date, under "Email Delivery Date". Cell C3 Contains a date as well. What is the formula or formulas that i am supposed to use in order to have those cells turn from green to yellow to red the further they get apart?

Ex. 1 day between the dates would be green, 3 days between the dates would be more yellow and anything past 7 days would be red.

If someone could help me I would appreciate it!!

I tried conditionally formatting the dates expecting for it to color code both columns but instead it just made them red to green dependent on if the date was closer or further from todays date, and not based on the distance between the dates.

Comment: Please confirm... which dates further apart? Is it the difference between Col B and Col C for each row?

Comment: Sorry for the mix up, if the columns are A, B, and C, I want it to format so the colors go from green to red, the further column C gets from column B. Or the later the form was returned versus the date it email was delivered.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you'll need 2 sets of conditional formatting rules: One for Column B, and one for Column C. But it can be done pretty easily. Just make sure to use relative cell references.

| Rule | Format | Applies to | Stop If True |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Formula: `=(C2-B2)<=1` | [Green] | `=$B$2:$B$10` | [checked] |
| Formula: `=(C2-B2)<=3` | [Yellow] | `=$B$2:$B$10` | [checked] |
| Formula: `=(C2-B2)>=7` | [Red] | `=$B$2:$B$10` | [checked] |

Then just repeat the same set of rules for Column C, changing the *Applies To* accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Why B8 is white while date difference is 6 days?

Comment: @rotabor: because OP's example specification didn't include a rule for 6 days. But you could easily adjust the conditional formatting as needed.

Answer (score -1):

1. Goto VBA editor, add a module to the project and paste there the next code:

```
Sub ApplyFormatting()
  Dim cc As Range
  ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="Date1", RefersToR1C1:="=RC[-1]+1"
  ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="Date3", RefersToR1C1:="=RC[-1]+3"
  ActiveSheet.Names.Add Name:="Date7", RefersToR1C1:="=RC[-1]+7"
  For Each cc In Selection.Cells
    With cc
      .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
      .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
      With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "=Date1"
        .FormatColor.Color = 5287936
      End With
      With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "=Date3"
        .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
      End With
      With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3)
        .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
        .Value = "=Date7"
        .FormatColor.Color = 255
      End With
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

2. Select the desired range (B2:B7), press Alt+F8 and run ApplyFormatting macro.

[image]

Use references according to the location of your data. Macro is used to help defining names and applying formatting to each cell.

Comment: Thank you for the help but there is one minor tweak that I would like to see. I don't want the dates to get red in relation to B2, I want them to go from green to red based on how far they are from delivery date. So instead of comparing all to B2, comparing A2 to B2, A5 to B5, etc.

Comment: Yes, I didn't fully test the solution. Now it works.

Comment: How is it going?